# How to merge rows that contain almost similar data in google sheet using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am collecting responses from a google form to my google spreadsheet and I will be receiving input with different values pairs for example

```
Name       |Present|Absent|Sick|Debate|
john Brown | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
Paul Doe   | 0     |1     |0   |0     |
John Brown | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
Mary Rose  | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
Paul Doe   | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
Mary Rose  | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
John Brown | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
Paul Doe   | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
Mary Rose  | 1     |0     |0   |1     |
..
```

How do I check for repeated NAME values maintain them and update the PRESENT, ABSENT, SICK, and DEBATE values using apps script code or an add-on if there is any.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are multiple possible ways to do this, either with App Scripts or by creating a new sheet that consolidates the collected data with formulas. Can you please enrich your question with an explanation of your own attempt(s)?

Comment: To be sure I understand, what you want is to just have a list where the names show up once and the other data is updated?

Comment: `=query(A1:E10,"select A, Sum(B), Sum(C),Sum(D),Sum(E)   group by A label Sum(B) 'Present', Sum(C) 'Absent',Sum(D) 'Sick',Sum(E) 'Debate'",-1)`